# JQuery Mobile Select Keyboard Operation not working?

Tags: jquery-mobile, select, keyboard

If you tab to a JQuery Mobile (1.2 - 1.3) enhanced select, I would expect [down arrow] to either select options or to open up the selectable options as if you had clicked/tapped on the select. What I am finding is that the underlying select is apparently being made, but the options list is not shown and the currently visible selected option is not changing.

See http://jsfiddle.net/F9w67/

```
<form>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input id="start" type="text" placeholder="start here and tab">
    <select name="select-native-1" id="select-native-1" onchange="alert($('#select-native-1').val())">
        <option calue="0">Choose with keyboard ...</option>
        <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
        <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
        <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
        <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

Click in the first input box and then without using the mouse, tab to the select and try to select an option with the keyboard. Nothing apparently changes until you exit the select, when you will see that the underlying value has changed. IF you remove JQuery Mobile, you will see the expected operation.

Is this a bug or a feature and what would be the easiest way to allow keyboard only operation?

Additional Info: This seems to be more complicated than I thought. In JQM 1.2.0, there only seems to be an issue with FF.  In JQM 1.3.2 there is unexpected behavior in Chrome, IE and Safari too.

What happens now is that once on the select, pressing down arrow causes the first option to be selected, but then focus is lost - so subsequent keystrokes are not accepted. This also breaks the behavior of finding an option by pressing several keys in quick succession. e.g. "A" quickly followed by "3" should select "A3 - Test" from the list:

```
<option>A1 - Test 1</option>
<option>A2 - Test 2</option>
<option>A3 - Test 3</option>
<option>3 - Test 4></option>
```

Comment: I am also facing the exact same issue.

Comment: I just ran into this issue? Is there a solution?